# how can i extract tomcat in ubuntu image in aws.I tried so many time to extract it bt all the commands are not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat

I have downloaded Tomcat in an Ubuntu image in AWS, but one command is not working while extracting Tomcat. How can I extract `tomcat.tar.gz`?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-72:/opt$ sudo tar xzvf apache-tomcat-9*tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1
Error:
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

how can i overcome this problem

Comment: You probably didn't download the file correctly. It should be roughly 30 MB in size, and you should verify the checksum as described on the download page.

Comment: yes,exactly you get my point.So how can i download the tomcat package in ubuntu server?

Comment: I would go to the website and find a URL that will download to my PC, then paste that into a `wget` command. What did you do?